# Grafana does not display any InfluxDB data ( failed to fetch ) after 60s for large datasets

Tags: monitoring, grafana, influxdb

Grafana does not display any data ( failed to fetch ) after 60s for large datasets but when the interval is smaller dashboard loads fine any help here?

Tried tweaking timeouts in grafana.ini does not seem to help here looks like Grafana has a hard - limit on those parameters

Grafana version > 7.0.3
Data source : influxdb
dashboard loads fine for smaller intervals
any help here would be appreciated here?

Answer (score 1):

Use time groupping `GROUP BY time($__interval)` in your InfluxDB query - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/influxdb/#query-editor - Grafana already has macro `$__interval` which will select "optimal" time aggregation based on current dashboard time range.

It doesn't make sense to load huge datasets with original granularity. You may solve it on the Grafana level somehow, but then you may have a problem in the browser - it may not have so much memory or it will take ages.